# Delay when loading image from Internet into CircleImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want load image from `JSON` into `Imageview`. When I use basic android `Imageview` there is no delay and it shows image quickly, but when I use **`CircleImageView`** the images are delayed and sometimes don't show the image.

I use `Glide` library for showing images in `ImageView`.

**My CircleImageView class :**

```
public class CircularImage extends ImageView {
    private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

    // Default Values
    private static final float DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 4;
    private static final float DEFAULT_SHADOW_RADIUS = 8.0f;

    // Properties
    private float borderWidth;
    private int canvasSize;
    private float shadowRadius;
    private int shadowColor = Color.BLACK;

    // Object used to draw
    private Bitmap image;
    private Drawable drawable;
    private Paint paint;
    private Paint paintBorder;

    //region Constructor & Init Method
    public tellfa_CircularImage(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public tellfa_CircularImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public tellfa_CircularImage(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        // Init paint
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        paintBorder = new Paint();
        paintBorder.setAntiAlias(true);

        // Load the styled attributes and set their properties
        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircularImageView, defStyleAttr, 0);

        // Init Border
        if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_border, true)) {
            float defaultBorderSize = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH * getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
            setBorderWidth(attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_border_width, defaultBorderSize));
            setBorderColor(attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_border_color, Color.WHITE));
        }

        // Init Shadow
        if (attributes.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_shadow, false)) {
            shadowRadius = DEFAULT_SHADOW_RADIUS;
            drawShadow(attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_shadow_radius, shadowRadius), attributes.getColor(R.styleable.CircularImageView_civ_shadow_color, shadowColor));
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Set Attr Method
    public void setBorderWidth(float borderWidth) {
        this.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        requestLayout();
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setBorderColor(int borderColor) {
        if (paintBorder != null)
            paintBorder.setColor(borderColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void addShadow() {
        if (shadowRadius == 0)
            shadowRadius = DEFAULT_SHADOW_RADIUS;
        drawShadow(shadowRadius, shadowColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setShadowRadius(float shadowRadius) {
        drawShadow(shadowRadius, shadowColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    public void setShadowColor(int shadowColor) {
        drawShadow(shadowRadius, shadowColor);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public ScaleType getScaleType() {
        return SCALE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
        if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported. ScaleType.CENTER_CROP is used by default. So you don't need to use ScaleType.", scaleType));
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Draw Method
    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Load the bitmap
        loadBitmap();

        // Check if image isn't null
        if (image == null)
            return;

        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            canvasSize = canvas.getWidth();
            if (canvas.getHeight() < canvasSize) {
                canvasSize = canvas.getHeight();
            }
        }

        // circleCenter is the x or y of the view's center
        // radius is the radius in pixels of the cirle to be drawn
        // paint contains the shader that will texture the shape
        int circleCenter = (int) (canvasSize - (borderWidth * 2)) / 2;
        // Draw Border
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth - (shadowRadius + shadowRadius / 2), paintBorder);
        // Draw CircularImageView
        canvas.drawCircle(circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter + borderWidth, circleCenter - (shadowRadius + shadowRadius / 2), paint);
    }

    private void loadBitmap() {
        if (this.drawable == getDrawable())
            return;

        this.drawable = getDrawable();
        this.image = drawableToBitmap(this.drawable);
        updateShader();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasSize = w;
        if (h < canvasSize)
            canvasSize = h;
        if (image != null)
            updateShader();
    }

    private void drawShadow(float shadowRadius, int shadowColor) {
        this.shadowRadius = shadowRadius;
        this.shadowColor = shadowColor;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
        }
        paintBorder.setShadowLayer(shadowRadius, 0.0f, shadowRadius / 2, shadowColor);
    }

    private void updateShader() {
        if (image == null)
            return;

        // Crop Center Image
        image = cropBitmap(image);

        // Create Shader
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(image, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        // Center Image in Shader
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.setScale((float) canvasSize / (float) image.getWidth(), (float) canvasSize / (float) image.getHeight());
        shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

        // Set Shader in Paint
        paint.setShader(shader);
    }

    private Bitmap cropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap bmp;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() >= bitmap.getHeight()) {
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bitmap,
                    bitmap.getWidth() / 2 - bitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                    0,
                    bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getHeight());
        } else {
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    bitmap,
                    0,
                    bitmap.getHeight() / 2 - bitmap.getWidth() / 2,
                    bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth());
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    private Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable) {
        if (drawable == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
            return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        }

        int intrinsicWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int intrinsicHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        if (!(intrinsicWidth > 0 && intrinsicHeight > 0))
            return null;

        try {
            // Create Bitmap object out of the drawable
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intrinsicWidth, intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            drawable.draw(canvas);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            // Simply return null of failed bitmap creations
            Log.e(getClass().toString(), "Encountered OutOfMemoryError while generating bitmap!");
            return null;
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Mesure Method
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = measureWidth(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = measureHeight(heightMeasureSpec);
        /*int imageSize = (width < height) ? width : height;
        setMeasuredDimension(imageSize, imageSize);*/
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private int measureWidth(int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // The parent has determined an exact size for the child.
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child.
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int measureHeight(int measureSpecHeight) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpecHeight);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpecHeight);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            // We were told how big to be
            result = specSize;
        } else if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
            // The child can be as large as it wants up to the specified size.
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            // Measure the text (beware: ascent is a negative number)
            result = canvasSize;
        }

        return (result + 2);
    }
    //endregion
}
```

**CircleImageview** is important to my project and I need to use **CirlceImageView** instead of basic `ImageView`.

How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should call init method in all the constructors--

```
                OR
```

Try this:

```
public class CircleImageView extends ImageView {

private static final ScaleType SCALE_TYPE = ScaleType.CENTER_CROP;

private static final Bitmap.Config BITMAP_CONFIG = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
private static final int COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION = 2;

private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH = 0;
private static final int DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR = Color.BLACK;
private static final int DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR = Color.TRANSPARENT;
private static final boolean DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY = false;

private final RectF mDrawableRect = new RectF();
private final RectF mBorderRect = new RectF();

private final Matrix mShaderMatrix = new Matrix();
private final Paint mBitmapPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mBorderPaint = new Paint();
private final Paint mFillPaint = new Paint();

private int mBorderColor = DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR;
private int mBorderWidth = DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH;
private int mFillColor = DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR;

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private BitmapShader mBitmapShader;
private int mBitmapWidth;
private int mBitmapHeight;

private float mDrawableRadius;
private float mBorderRadius;

private ColorFilter mColorFilter;

private boolean mReady;
private boolean mSetupPending;
private boolean mBorderOverlay;

public CircleImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public CircleImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CircleImageView, defStyle, 0);

    mBorderWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_width, DEFAULT_BORDER_WIDTH);
    mBorderColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_color, DEFAULT_BORDER_COLOR);
    mBorderOverlay = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_border_overlay, DEFAULT_BORDER_OVERLAY);
    mFillColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.CircleImageView_civ_fill_color, DEFAULT_FILL_COLOR);

    a.recycle();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    super.setScaleType(SCALE_TYPE);
    mReady = true;

    if (mSetupPending) {
        setup();
        mSetupPending = false;
    }
}

@Override
public ScaleType getScaleType() {
    return SCALE_TYPE;
}

@Override
public void setScaleType(ScaleType scaleType) {
    if (scaleType != SCALE_TYPE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("ScaleType %s not supported.", scaleType));
    }
}

@Override
public void setAdjustViewBounds(boolean adjustViewBounds) {
    if (adjustViewBounds) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adjustViewBounds not supported.");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (mBitmap == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (mFillColor != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mFillPaint);
    }
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mDrawableRadius, mBitmapPaint);
    if (mBorderWidth != 0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2.0f, getHeight() / 2.0f, mBorderRadius, mBorderPaint);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    setup();
}

public int getBorderColor() {
    return mBorderColor;
}

public void setBorderColor(@ColorInt int borderColor) {
    if (borderColor == mBorderColor) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderColor = borderColor;
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    invalidate();
}

public void setBorderColorResource(@ColorRes int borderColorRes) {
    setBorderColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(borderColorRes));
}

public int getFillColor() {
    return mFillColor;
}

public void setFillColor(@ColorInt int fillColor) {
    if (fillColor == mFillColor) {
        return;
    }

    mFillColor = fillColor;
    mFillPaint.setColor(fillColor);
    invalidate();
}

public void setFillColorResource(@ColorRes int fillColorRes) {
    setFillColor(getContext().getResources().getColor(fillColorRes));
}

public int getBorderWidth() {
    return mBorderWidth;
}

public void setBorderWidth(int borderWidth) {
    if (borderWidth == mBorderWidth) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderWidth = borderWidth;
    setup();
}

public boolean isBorderOverlay() {
    return mBorderOverlay;
}

public void setBorderOverlay(boolean borderOverlay) {
    if (borderOverlay == mBorderOverlay) {
        return;
    }

    mBorderOverlay = borderOverlay;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    super.setImageBitmap(bm);
    mBitmap = bm;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    super.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(drawable);
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
    mBitmap = getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable());
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    super.setImageURI(uri);
    mBitmap = uri != null ? getBitmapFromDrawable(getDrawable()) : null;
    setup();
}

@Override
public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    if (cf == mColorFilter) {
        return;
    }

    mColorFilter = cf;
    mBitmapPaint.setColorFilter(mColorFilter);
    invalidate();
}

private Bitmap getBitmapFromDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    if (drawable == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    }

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, COLORDRAWABLE_DIMENSION, BITMAP_CONFIG);
        } else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), BITMAP_CONFIG);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private void setup() {
    if (!mReady) {
        mSetupPending = true;
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 && getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (mBitmap == null) {
        invalidate();
        return;
    }

    mBitmapShader = new BitmapShader(mBitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    mBitmapPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBitmapPaint.setShader(mBitmapShader);

    mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mBorderPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderPaint.setColor(mBorderColor);
    mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(mBorderWidth);

    mFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mFillPaint.setColor(mFillColor);

    mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();

    mBorderRect.set(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    mBorderRadius = Math.min((mBorderRect.height() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f, (mBorderRect.width() - mBorderWidth) / 2.0f);

    mDrawableRect.set(mBorderRect);
    if (!mBorderOverlay) {
        mDrawableRect.inset(mBorderWidth, mBorderWidth);
    }
    mDrawableRadius = Math.min(mDrawableRect.height() / 2.0f, mDrawableRect.width() / 2.0f);

    updateShaderMatrix();
    invalidate();
}

private void updateShaderMatrix() {
    float scale;
    float dx = 0;
    float dy = 0;

    mShaderMatrix.set(null);

    if (mBitmapWidth * mDrawableRect.height() > mDrawableRect.width() * mBitmapHeight) {
        scale = mDrawableRect.height() / (float) mBitmapHeight;
        dx = (mDrawableRect.width() - mBitmapWidth * scale) * 0.5f;
    } else {
        scale = mDrawableRect.width() / (float) mBitmapWidth;
        dy = (mDrawableRect.height() - mBitmapHeight * scale) * 0.5f;
    }

    mShaderMatrix.setScale(scale, scale);
    mShaderMatrix.postTranslate((int) (dx + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.left, (int) (dy + 0.5f) + mDrawableRect.top);

    mBitmapShader.setLocalMatrix(mShaderMatrix);
}

}
```

styles:

```
<declare-styleable name="CircleImageView">
    <attr name="civ_border_width" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="civ_border_color" format="color" />
    <attr name="civ_border_overlay" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="civ_fill_color" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: Please send to me Style.xml attr for this CircleImageView

Comment: there you go @Palang

Comment: Thanks @Abraham Gharyali, it's fast a few but not such base imageView :(

Comment: have u tried calling the init() method from all your constructors

Comment: are you online? when you are online please say me . thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111604/discussion-between-abraham-gharyali-and-palang).

Answer (score 0):

[Use this library for showing circle imageview, it is very effective.](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Comment: I use this library, but i have this bug

Comment: what bug you are getting